# Qt draw text on a point aligned by its center

Tags: c++, qt

Sounds simple, I want to draw text at a point on the display, so that it is aligned both horizontally and vertically by its centre.

However it doesn't appear to be quite so simple, I've used other libraries where all I have to do is set the text alignment, then draw the text at the specified point.

Qt isn't so simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even we use FTGL to render texts.

But in QT there is method for controlling alignment.

I guess you use `QPainter::drawText` to draw the texts.

There is a library function:

```
void QPainter::drawText(int x, int y, int width, int height, int flags, const QString & text, QRect * boundingRect = 0)
```

Here the **flags** argument is a bitwise OR operator with lot of alignment options.

I think for your case, you can use `Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter`

Refer documentation:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawText-13

Comment: Thank you, I know that much, the issue is that it isn't quite that simple.

Comment: ok. Shall I delete the post?

Comment: Try it and see if it works for you?

Comment: Ok. Will give a try.